# How to validate text format in column for ANY number of entries?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, column, validation

I am trying to validate any number of entries in a SharePoint form "multiple line of text" field to ensure they follow a specific format (if this will not work with multiple, I could make do with "single line of text" field). I know how to validate text format for a SINGLE entry in the field, but not sure how to validate ANY number of entries in the field.

The end user can submit a form that corresponds to any number of unique IDs that need to be captured in a field in the following format:

XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,...

All numerical. It could be a single 9 digit number in the field, or a series of them (from 1 to X...25 would be the limit if single line of text field). Is it possible to use data validation on the column to ensure each 9 digit number entered is separated by a comma? With the constraint that if it's a single number, a comma wouldn't be needed.

The form will be created in InfoPath, and I do not have access to SharePoint designer or ability to add any custom coding (security reasons)...only out of the box solutions.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below validation rule in infopath

([0-9]{9})+(,([0-9]{9})+)*

This should satisfy the [0-9] numbers which should be 9 digit ("{9}") and comma seperated multiple times.